# How to reference a multiline string in another multiline string in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I have 2 multiline strings entries defined in my YAML, as presentence below. How do I inject the configOverwrites content into  migrationConfigOverwrites so that i can continue to add to it? What I've tried below doesn't seem to work :

```
configOverwrites: &configOverwrites |
  [sqlalchemy]
  url = http://myurls
migrationConfigOverwrites: 
  <<: *configOverwrites |
  [logger_sqlalchemy]
  level = INFOs
```

The output I'm expecting should be something on this line:

```
migrationConfigOverwrites: 
  [sqlalchemy]
  url = http://myurl
  [logger_sqlalchemy]
  level = INFO
```

Comment: YAML cannot do that itself. The `<<` Merge Key can only be used to merge mappings, not strings or sequences.

Comment: I guess I won't have other option but to hardcoded the values in both places. Thanks